# What is the difference between a stream and channel in ffmpeg?

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, mp4, webm

The documentation refers to streams but it is not clear if an audio channel is a stream or whether a stream contains multiple audio channels.

Comment: The latter is the correct interpretation: 'whether a stream contains multiple audio channels.'

Comment: e.g. a 5.1 audio streams contains 6 channels

Comment: Thanks both. I'm interested in MP4 and WebM. I can't see streams as separate from channels (at least where audio is concerned). Do you have a reference?